ETH Transaction confirmed after sending to EasyCrypto Address but balance not reflected
In March 2024, I created a sell order for 0.93 ETH on EasyCrypto. However, when attempting to transfer the ETH from my wallet to EasyCrypto's address, I discovered that my wallet had a balance of 0.00 ETH.
Upon investigation, I found that in July 2022, I had sold 0.93 ETH and transferred it to the same EasyCrypto address. Despite the transaction being successful and confirmed on etherscan.io, I never received the funds for this transaction, and the order was never confirmed on EasyCrypto.
I verified that both addresses were typed correctly. Upon contacting EasyCrypto, they informed me that due to the transaction being from a while ago, it would take some time to locate it.
Considering the absence of an order setup, does entitlement to an ETH refund exist?
Seeking advice from anyone who may have encountered similar issues.
Thanks

Can you provide more details? EasyCrypto seems to be an exchange. Unless you have some control over the addresses or contracts involved there's little you could do until they answer.
